# AJAX call response not showing anything

Tags: php, ajax

I have this input field.

```
<input type="email" name="email"  required/>
```

When submit button is clicked, it goes into :

```
$(".store_email").click(function() 
{
    var ajax_url_store_email = "store_email.php";
    var value= document.getElementsByName('email')[0].value;


    $.post(ajax_url_store_email, {act:"Subscribe", value:value}, function(e){
      console.log(e);

    });
});
```

And the call is sent to:

```
$email=$_POST["value"];
 $verify= $link->query(" INSERT INTO `Subscribers_email`(`email`) VALUES ('$email') ");
        if($verify==true)
        {
            return json_encode( "Success!");
        }
        else
        {
         return json_encode("Something went wrong!");
        }
```

Everything is working fine, But this call is not returning anything. I mean the `console.log(e);` prints nothing, what could be the reason?

Comment: please check your ajax

Comment: try echo and exit instead of return in php code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

plus other answers you must set json dataType in $.post function if you want to return values as json :

```
$.post(ajax_url_store_email, {act:"Subscribe", value:value}, function(e){
  console.log(e);
},'json');
```

Answer (score 1):

To return a response to the ajax request, you must `echo` not `return`:

```
if($verify==true){
    echo json_encode( "Success!");
}
else{
    echo json_encode("Something went wrong!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try **echo** and exit instead of **return**

```
$verify= $link->query(" INSERT INTO `Subscribers_email`(`email`) VALUES ('$email') ");
        if($verify==true)
        {
            echo json_encode( "Success!");
        }
        else
        {
         echo json_encode("Something went wrong!");
        }
         exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use PHP [print](http://php.net/manual/es/function.print.php) or [echo](http://php.net/manual/es/function.echo.php) function instead of return.